# What is the meaning please

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I read the sentence  below in timesmagazinus.com. Please let me know its meaning.
Dude English is my second language.

> *Do you think Jesus might've been institutionalized during our times? But then again, he might pass for one of those zealot preachers on TV. Anyhow, at least no crucifixions today!*

Comment: There are three sentences. Which one is unclear, and what don't you understand?

Comment: I want to know about there construction if they  imply deduction in present or past.

Comment: Deduction as in formal logic? You'd probably get into a discussion about the difference between logical deduction versus induction versus reduction. Although I'm not sure I see anything of the kind in those sentences, I doubt a discussion on logic is something for this site. The three sentences simply imply how the modern world might receive a person like Jesus, offering two options (he's mad or he's a TV-preacher) and the observation that at least he would not be crucified in today's world.

Answer (score 2):

In simple language, the statement appears to ask the reader if Jesus would be considered mentally ill, should he exist today. Or, perhaps, he would be an televangelist (an evangelist on TV). Either way, the statement goes on to suppose, he wouldn't be nailed to a cross.

Does that help?